# why does emacs stop superuser from editing files without permissions?

Tags: editors, text

If I have a file I want to edit, as root, I should have the ability to modify it regarless of the permissions.  But this does not seem to be the case with all text editors, emacs in particular.

If there is a text file with any of the following permissions, with the permissions `-rw-r--r--`, `-r--rw-r--`, or `-r--r--rw-` then as root, I can edit the file, no problem.
However, if there are no write permissions at all (`-r--r--r--`),
then `emacs` will not allow root to even make changes to the buffer.  Vim behaves in a slightly quirky way as well.  For the first three cases, it will allow root to save changes with the `:w` command, but in the last case, root must use the override `:w!` command to save.

Both `nano` and `gedit` behave properly, giving the super user write access all the time.

Does anyone know what the source of this obnoxious behavior is on the part of `emacs` and `vim`?  I'm inclined to think it's more of a side-effect of something, rather than an intentional design, based on vim's behavior, but I can't think of what would cause this.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a case of `vim` and `emacs` exposing what is going on under the hood. When there are no write permissions available to the file, it is not being edited in-place. Instead, the file is entirely replaced (since that depends on directory permissions, not file permissions).

To save a file in `emacs` that does not have write permissions, you can use `M-x toggle-read-only` or `C-x C-q`. You will then be able to save your modifications.